# `Java 8 in Action` is wrong about the demo it provided?

Tags: java, asynchronous, java-8, completable-future

This code is a quoted from [Java 8 in Action](https://github.com/java8/Java8InAction/blob/master/src/main/java/lambdasinaction/chap11/BestPriceFinder.java), which is also in the book 11.4.3.

```
public Stream<CompletableFuture<String>> findPricesStream(String product) {
    return shops.stream()
            .map(shop -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> shop.getPrice(product), executor))
            .map(future -> future.thenApply(Quote::parse))
            .map(future -> future.thenCompose(quote -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> Discount.applyDiscount(quote), executor)));
}
```

Along the code, the writer enclose a **figure** as follows expressing that the `applyDiscount()` works in the same thread with `getPrice()`, which I strongly have a doubt: there are two different **Async** suffix here which means the second call should be in **another** thread.

[image]

I tested it locally with the following code:

```
private static void testBasic() {
    out.println("*****************************************");
    out.println("********** TESTING thenCompose **********");
    CompletableFuture[] futures = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, LEN).boxed()
            .map(i -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> runStage1(i), EXECUTOR_SERVICE))
            .map(future -> future.thenCompose(i -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> runStage2(i), EXECUTOR_SERVICE)))
            .toArray(size -> new CompletableFuture[size]);
    CompletableFuture.allOf(futures).join();
}
```

The output further demonstrate my thought, is it correct?

```
*****************************************
********** TESTING thenCompose **********
Start: stage - 1 - value: 0 - thread name: pool-1-thread-1
Start: stage - 1 - value: 1 - thread name: pool-1-thread-2
Start: stage - 1 - value: 2 - thread name: pool-1-thread-3
Start: stage - 1 - value: 3 - thread name: pool-1-thread-4
Finish: stage - 1 - value: 3 - thread name: pool-1-thread-4 - time cost: 1520
Start: stage - 2 - value: 3 - thread name: pool-1-thread-5
Finish: stage - 1 - value: 0 - thread name: pool-1-thread-1 - time cost: 1736
Start: stage - 2 - value: 0 - thread name: pool-1-thread-6
Finish: stage - 1 - value: 2 - thread name: pool-1-thread-3 - time cost: 1761
Start: stage - 2 - value: 2 - thread name: pool-1-thread-7
Finish: stage - 2 - value: 2 - thread name: pool-1-thread-7 - time cost: 446
Finish: stage - 1 - value: 1 - thread name: pool-1-thread-2 - time cost: 2249
Start: stage - 2 - value: 1 - thread name: pool-1-thread-8
Finish: stage - 2 - value: 3 - thread name: pool-1-thread-5 - time cost: 828
Finish: stage - 2 - value: 0 - thread name: pool-1-thread-6 - time cost: 704
Finish: stage - 2 - value: 1 - thread name: pool-1-thread-8 - time cost: 401
```

The `Java 8 in Action` is wrong about this?

Thank you, @Holger. You make it crystal clear to me now about the **executing thread** for **async** and **non-async** methods. Especially after checking its [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) further demonstrating your point.

> Actions supplied for dependent completions of **non-async** methods **may** be performed by the thread that completes the current CompletableFuture, or by any other caller of a completion method.

Comment: I think the figure was meant to indicate that the execution will happen in another thread than the calling thread, not necessarily the _same_ other thread for both calls. Note that due to the way executors work, they _could_ land in the same thread though. Illustrations like these are just that - illustrations. They are not proper specifications. Note that it doesn't really matter which other thread the two calls happen in because they are guaranteed to be _sequential_ (w.r.t. to teach other).

Comment: Yes, you should be right about it. Executor can manage the threads scheduling indeed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As a first note, that code is distracting from what’s happening due to the unnecessary splitting into multiple Stream operations.

Further, there is no sense in doing

```
future.thenCompose(quote ->
    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> Discount.applyDiscount(quote), executor))
```

instead of

```
future.thenApplyAsync(quote -> Discount.applyDiscount(quote), executor)
```

So, a simpler example doing the same would be

```
public Stream<CompletableFuture<String>> findPricesStream(String product) {
    return shops.stream().map(
        shop -> CompletableFuture
            .supplyAsync(() -> shop.getPrice(product), executor)
            .thenApply(Quote::parse)
            .thenApplyAsync(quote -> Discount.applyDiscount(quote), executor));
}
```

However, you are right, there is no guaranty that `getPrice` and `applyDiscount` run in the same thread—unless the executor is a single threaded executor.

You may interpret “executor thread” as “one of the executor’s threads”, but even then, there in a dangerously wrong point in the diagram, namely, “`new Quote(price)`”, which apparently actually means “`Quote::parse`”. That step does *not* belong to the right side, as the actual thread evaluating the function passed to `thenApply` is unspecified. It may be one of the executor’s threads upon completion of the previous stage, but it may also be “your thread” right when calling `thenApply`, e.g. if the asynchronous operation managed to complete in‑between.

The `CompletableFuture` offers no way to enforce the use of the first stage’s completing thread for the dependent actions.

Unless you use a simple sequential code instead, of course:

```
public Stream<CompletableFuture<String>> findPricesStream(String product) {
    return shops.stream().map(shop -> CompletableFuture
        .supplyAsync(() -> Discount.applyDiscount(Quote.parse(shop.getPrice(product))), executor));
}
```

Then, the picture of a linear thread on the right hand side will be correct.