# CompletableFuture: transformation vs. composition

Tags: java, mapping, completable-future

Please, consider an example from the *"Modern Java in Action" book (2nd Edition, listing 16.16, page 405)*. There, we have three map operation to obtain the list of discounted prices for the product from all the shops in a stream. First, we contact each shop to get a response containing non-discounted price along with a discount type, than parse the response into Quote object, and pass it over to the remote Discount service which returns a string with already discounted price.

```java
public List<String> findPrices(String product) {

    List<CompletableFuture<String>> priceFutures =
        shops.stream()
            .map(shop -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
                    () -> shop.getPrice(product), executor))
            .map(future -> future.thenApply(Quote::parse))
            .map(future -> future.thenCompose(quote ->
                    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
                        () -> Discount.applyDiscount(quote), executor)))
            .collect(toList());

    return priceFutures.stream()
            .map(CompletableFuture::join)
            .collect(toList());
}
```

My question is not about the difference between `thenApply` and `thenCompose`. I believe, the latter is used to avoid nested construction like `CompletableFuture<CompletableFuture<...>>`. What I don't understand, though, why we need to create another level of `CompletableFuture` here at all? It seems like the author added some artificial complexity to the code by creating and then flattening nested `CompletableFuture`, instead of simply using `thenApplyAsync` in the third map like this:

```java
            .map(shop -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
                    () -> shop.getPrice(product), executor))
            .map(future -> future.thenApply(Quote::parse))
            .map(future -> future.thenApplyAsync(Discount::applyDiscount, executor))
```

Are those two mapping usages (the original with `thenCompose` and the one with `thenApplyAsync`) equivalent? Both accept the result of the previous mapping as an argument, both provide custom executor to perform the task, and both return the same `CompletableFuture<String>` result.

Comment: See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50854568/2711488), which seems to discuss another aspect of the same chapter (can’t verify whether “listing 16.16, page 405” is the same as 11.4.3). The answer addresses the point that `thenCompose(quote -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> Discount.applyDiscount(quote), executor))` is indeed a verbose version of `thenApplyAsync`, and the splitting into multiple `Stream.map` operations doesn’t add to the readability as well.

Comment: You should also avoid calling `CompletableFuture.join` **unless you're certain it will not block**, as it may result in deadlocks (for instance, if `findPrices` is called asynchronously as well and it uses an executor with a bounded number of threads).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `thenCompose` and `supplyAsync` achieve the same as using `thenApplyAsync` directly.

I haven't read the book, but it might be that some example code is focused on some topic or feature rather than the most concise or fastest code.  As such, I leave some suggestions assuming you're considering using similar code.

---

One more suggestion about this code is that it's kind of weird to chain each `CompletableFuture` through successive calls to `map`.  It seems the current example was built on top of a previous `Stream` based method with multiple calls, and left as-is but with the use of `CompletableFuture`.

I prefer one single `map` and chaining each `CompletableFuture` directly, which also allows refactoring it out into a method of its own.

So this:

```
            .map(shop -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
                    () -> shop.getPrice(product), executor))
            .map(future -> future.thenApply(Quote::parse))
            .map(future -> future.thenApplyAsync(Discount::applyDiscount, executor))
```

Would become this:

```
            .map(shop ->
                CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> shop.getPrice(product), executor)
                .thenApply(Quote::parse)
                .thenApplyAsync(Discount::applyDiscount, executor))
```

This lambda is easily turned into a method, which can be reused in cases without a `Stream`, it can be composed with another `CompletableFuture`, it can be tested, it can be mocked, etc.

---

Another suggestion would be to make your code *asynchronous all the way*, such that `findPrices` doesn't block on `join` (or `get`, for that matter).

The problem with blocking is that it might block the last available thread on an executor, thus provoking a deadlock by thread exhaustion.  The asynchronous code on which your code depends on, that eventually needs to run on the executor, might never run.

```
public CompletableFuture<List<String>> findPricesAsync(String product) {
    // List<CompletableFuture<String>> priceFutures = ...

    CompletableFuture<Void> all = CompletableFuture.allOf(priceFutures.toArray(new CompletableFuture<String>[priceFutures.size()]));
    return all.thenRun(() -> priceFutures.stream()
        .map(CompletableFuture::join));
}
```

Note that the return type changed from `List<String>` to `CompletableFuture<List<String>>`.  Also note that the last call to `join` will not block, as every `CompletableFuture` on which it will be called has completed.

---

Finally, I tend to return `CompletionStage`, as it allows hypothetical implementations other than `CompletableFuture`.  I also make the assumption that the returned object also implements `Future`, which allows to use `get` on the result, but not `join`, the difference being the declared thrown exception types.

In one case where I made NIO-like methods return `CompletionStage` for asynchronous I/O, I've implemented a subclass of `CompletableFuture` overriding the default executor used in each `*Async` method that doesn't have the executor parameter.  This was made easier since Java 9, still by subclassing, but it only needs overriding `defaultExecutor`.  The main reason I subclassed was that the alternative using composition would result in **much** more code (wrapping results and what not).  Another reason, but not what really worried me, was having an extra object to be garbage collected for each instance.

This was just to demonstrate that there may be cases where having custom `CompletionStage` implementations is actually needed, which might or might not be subclasses of `CompletableFuture`.