# Will a chain of method calls (CompletableFuture API) execute asynchronously if the first method in a chain is asynchronous?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, concurrency, completable-future

I'm studying CompletableFuture API and there is an example:

```
CompletableFuture.completedFuture(url)
                 .thenComposeAsync(this::readPage, executor)
                 .thenApply(this::getImageURLs)
                 .thenApply(this::saveFoundImages)
                 .....
```

I have a question: if I call the `thenComposeAsync(...)` method as the first one, will the other methods in the chain execute in the `executor` which I passed through the params, or I should call the other methods using *async* to get asynchronous execution in a particular executor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, so there are 3 types of methods in `CompletableFuture`. For example:

- `thenApply()`
- `thenApplyAsync(Function)` (without an Executor)
- `thenApplyAsync(Function, Executor)` (with an Executor)

The *last* one means that this action will execute in the `Executor` that you pass to it and it is the most obvious one.

The *second* one means that the action is executed in the `ForkJoinPool`.

The *first* one is far more interesting. The documentation makes it sound like it's easy, via:

> Actions supplied for **dependent completions** of non-async methods may be performed by the thread **that completes the current CompletableFuture**, or by **any other caller of a completion method**

And you need to start bisecting this into smaller pieces. What you need to understand that there are threads that *complete* a certain `CompletableFuture`, there are threads that *execute* some actions on it and there are threads that *chain* certain dependent actions. Potentially, these are all *different* threads. And this is where it all begins:

- If the dependent action is already chained, the thread that will call `complete` is going to be the thread that executes this action.
- If the future is already completed, then the thread that chains the action will execute it.

Since there is no linear actions on the steps above, it is literally impossible to say for sure in which thread your `thenApply` will execute, at least with 100% certainty. That action can be executed in any of :

- the thread that calls `complete/completeExceptionally`
- the thread that does the chaining of `thenApply`
- the thread that calls `join/get`

Any of the above is a possibility. If you really want I made a rather interesting [test here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63217097/is-the-writers-reason-correct-for-using-thencompose-and-not-thencomposeasync/64884329#64884329), proving some of the things above.

---

I am not trying to pick on the other answer, but he made a rather interesting point that I was very confused about in the begging too:

> In your example: After `.thenComposeAsync` also all the following chained futures will get completed by executor.

We can easily prove that this is not correct:

```
 CompletableFuture<String> future1 = CompletableFuture.completedFuture("a");
 CompletableFuture<String> future2 = future1.thenApplyAsync(x -> "b" + x, Executors.newCachedThreadPool());

 LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1));

 CompletableFuture<String> future3 = future2.thenApply(x -> {
      System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
      return x + "c";
 });
 future3.join();
```

What you are going to see if you run this, is that `main` actually executes `thenApply`, not a thread from the pool.

Comment: I suppose, the second bullet, “If the action is already completed…” is supposed to mean “If the *future* is already completed”. It’s also worth noting that if there is a race between completion and action chaining, even more surprising results are possible (esp. with more than two threads). But yes, it’s much better now.