# CompletableFuture behaves differently when chained directly vs individually

Tags: java-8, java-11, completable-future

Folks I have been using CompletableFuture in my project and I experienced a strange behaviour. I would like to understand the behaviour. Kindly help

**Scenario 1:**
In the below code the output is **I am from supply  I am the first thenApply  I am the second thenApply** .. As expected

```
public void callAll(){
        String calculatedDistance = listBuildComp().stream()
                .map(CompletableFuture::join)
                .collect(Collectors.joining());
        System.out.println(calculatedDistance);
    }
    private List<CompletableFuture<String>> listBuildComp(){
        List<CompletableFuture<String>> result = new ArrayList<>();
        result.add(buildComp());
        return result;
    }

    private CompletableFuture<String> buildComp(){
        CompletableFuture<String> workFlowWithServices =
                CompletableFuture.supplyAsync( () -> "I am from supply ")
        .thenApply( x -> {
            return x.concat(" I am the first thenApply ");
        })
        .thenApply( x -> {
            return x.concat(" I am the second thenApply ");
        });
        return workFlowWithServices;
    }
```

**Scenario 2**:
When the below method is changed then the output is **I am from supply** . Upon further investigation I see that the rest two thenApply runs in their own thread

```
private CompletableFuture<String> buildComp(){
        CompletableFuture<String> workFlowWithServices =
                CompletableFuture.supplyAsync( () -> "I am from supply ");
        
        workFlowWithServices.thenApply( x -> {
            return x.concat(" I am the first thenApply ");
        });
        
        workFlowWithServices.thenApply( x -> {
            return x.concat(" I am the second thenApply ");
        });
        return workFlowWithServices;
    }
```

The reason I am interested with **Scenario 2** is imagine you are chaining 2 TASKS then Scenario 1 is okay but imagine you want to chain 50 TASKS then the method will get too big. In this case I wanted to extract each calls in to a method to begin with but eventually extract in to a class if required but I cannot do all these cause of Scenario 2.

Want to know the concept or idea about why scenario 2 behaves in a different way and if there is anyway to make it behave like scenario 1. Kindly share your knowledge. Thank you.

Comment: What is so surprising to the fact that ignoring return values leads to loss of the return values? When you write `string1.concat(" I am the first thenApply "); string1.concat(" I am the second thenApply ");` it’s exactly the the same, the `string1` variable still references the original string.

Comment: yes @Holger it does refer to the original one but this works in Scenario 1 as they all run one after the other while in scenario 2 all the three supplyAsync, thenApply and thenApply run in parallel.

Comment: Scenario 1 is like `String s = "a".concat("b").concat("c");` it is *using* the result of the method invocations. `CompletableFuture<String> f = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(…) .thenApply(…).thenApply(…);`  is not different. Scenario 2 is like `String s = "a"; s.concat("b") s.concat("c");` storing the first object and ignoring the other two, though the other two objects also are different, as it does matter on which object you invoke a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have [no guarantee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65685715/will-a-chain-of-method-calls-completablefuture-api-execute-asynchronously-if-t) which thread will execute those `thenApply`, it could easily be `main`.

Then in your example, you build a `CompletableFuture`:

```
CompletableFuture<String> workFlowWithServices =
       CompletableFuture.supplyAsync( () -> "I am from supply ");
```

chain some actions :

```
    workFlowWithServices.thenApply( x -> {
        System.out.println("executing");
        return x.concat(" I am the first thenApply ");
    })

   ...
```

but you *ignore* the result of that `thenApply` (which is a `CompletableFuture<String>` too). When you `join`, you `join` on `workFlowWithServices` which, when it's done, will return `"I am from supply "`. Done. You do not query (you ignore entirely) the result of subsequent actions in `thenApply`, thus they do execute, but the result is gone.

I do not get what exactly stops you to build something like this, for example:

```
 private static CompletableFuture<String> buildComp2(){
    CompletableFuture<String> one =
            CompletableFuture.supplyAsync( () -> "I am from supply ");

    CompletableFuture<String> two = one.thenApply( x -> {
        System.out.println("executing");
        return x.concat(" I am the first thenApply ");
    });

    CompletableFuture<String> three = two.thenApply( x -> {
        return x.concat(" I am the second thenApply ");
    });
    return three;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for a clear explanation especially buildComp2().