# Writing Asynchronous Rest API using Spring boot and CompletableFuture and its thread management

Tags: multithreading, spring-boot, tomcat, concurrency, completable-future

I have a question about thread management for the tomcat server and application. Here is a sample code:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/asyncCompletable", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public CompletableFuture<String> getValueAsyncUsingCompletableFuture() {

        logger.info("Request received");
        CompletableFuture<String> completableFuture
                = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::processRequest);
        logger.info("Servlet thread released");
        return completableFuture;

    }

    private String processRequest() {
        Long delayTime = 10000L;
        logger.info("Start processing request");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(delayTime);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        logger.info("Completed processing request");
        return "Processing done after " + delayTime;
    }
```

Here, This is a simple API using spring boot. What I have done here?

- It is simple endpoints that is a simple GET method and returning a string as a response.
- In method `getValueAsyncUsingCompletableFuture` I am calling `processRequest` on `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::processRequest)`. So obviously it will run under separate thread.
- In method `processRequest` where only have a `Thread.sleep` for 10s.
- Both methods have an entry and exit log.
- Also the API `getValueAsyncUsingCompletableFuture` is returning a `completableFuture`

Now after calling the Endpoints from the browser its output is as expected. It waits 10 seconds and provides a response. The output log is given below.
[image]

Here,

- The first and second line of log is showing under `nio-8080-exec-8` thread. It also showing request received and servlet thread released.
- In the last 2 lines of log for method `processRequest`. Here it is showing for `CompletableFuture` execution part. It is handling under `onPool-worker-2` thread.

**Now, Here is my question:**

1. During the execution of `processRequest` method, is it released the tomcat allocated thread `nio-8080-exec-8`? I am telling based on the log. Is this thread released and go back to tomcat connection pool?
2. If the tomcat thread released then how the client is getting a response after the execution of `completableFuture` is done?
3. Can you please describe how thread allocation occur when request come to tomcat server, and spring application.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you use the reactive stack? https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html

Comment: Sir, Thank you for your comments. As far as I know,  both WebFlux and CompletableFuture are doing actually the same things. For one of my R&D, I need an answer to these questions.

Comment: They are not doing the same thing because WebFlux is Non-blocking but MVC is blocking that means the Thread is blocked even if you are returning a completable future

Comment: 1. yes, 2. that is how the async part of the servlet-api works. 3. read the servlet spec which explains that.

Comment: "So obviously it will run under separate thread" you have to be very careful with your assumptions. While `supplyAsync` will indeed run in a different thread, the dependent actions [might not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65685715/will-a-chain-of-method-calls-completablefuture-api-execute-asynchronously-if-t/65691463#65691463)

Answer (score 2):

Spring uses the [`ServletRequest#startAsync()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/servletrequest#startAsync--) method introduced in Servlet 3.0 (see [Oracle's tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/servlets012.htm)). This means that:

1. The Tomcat thread `http-nio-8080-exec-8` is returned to its executor shortly after `getValueAsyncUsingCompletableFuture` is called, but the response is not yet committed to the client as in the synchronous case. Spring switches the `ServletRequest` into asynchronous mode whenever your handler returns a [`CompletionStage`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html).
2. After your method `getValueAsyncUsingCompletableFuture` exits, the `ServletRequest` and `ServletResponse` can still be used to send data to the client. Spring appends a stage to your `CompletableFuture`, which writes the result to `ServletResponse` and ends the request using `AsyncContext#complete()`. This stage can be executed on any thread. In your case it executes on the `ForkJoinPool` since you launched the `CompletableFuture` using the default executor. However any executor would be fine.
3. Tomcat allocates a thread to execute `getValueAsyncUsingCompletableFuture` (or more precisely `DispatcherServlet#service`). The rest of the allocations is up to you.

Comment: if Spring indeed attaches a stage, that stage can be executed outside of the `ForkJoinPool`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65685715/will-a-chain-of-method-calls-completablefuture-api-execute-asynchronously-if-t/65691463#65691463). But if they use a dedicated executor, than you are correct. I am very interested in the code where they do this

Comment: The stage is executed on the same thread as the previous stage (see [DeferredResultMethodResultValueHandler.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/4203e90655a3836fb564f32b6f5c978289e87d60/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/DeferredResultMethodReturnValueHandler.java#L93)). However you can change the `Executor` of the previous stage using a `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync` call with two arguments.

Comment: it calls `handle` there, and if by the time it is chained to the previous one, `CompletableFuture` is already completed, it will be called on the calling thread, not on the thread that does ``supplyAsync`